# Convert AM/PM to small case letters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string  `start's 7/28/2015 4:00 AM end's 7/31/2015 4:30 AM`.

I want that it should convert `AM/PM` as `am/pm` pragmatically in c#... please help 
me me!

Comment: If your string is exactly `"start's 7/28/2015 4:00 AM end's 7/31/2015 4:30 AM"`, just use `ToLower()` method on it as `"start's 7/28/2015 4:00 AM end's 7/31/2015 4:30 AM".ToLower()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.ToLower`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx) Method like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString().ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always wants date/time in that format. You better to use [InvarientCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a(v=vs.90).aspx) when ToString.

```
string text = 
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also separate AM/PM format via `tt` string formatter, just in case you would want to only make the `AM/PM` lower-case and not the whole date (for cases like ex: `August 3, 2015 3:00 pm`

```
//If it happens that you will have a formatted string like "August 3, 2015 3:00 pm"
//It's is better to separate the 'AM/PM' format via `tt` formatter.
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string formatted1 = now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm ") + now.ToString("tt").ToLower();
Console.WriteLine(formatted1);

string formatted2 = now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm ") + now.ToString("tt").ToLower();
Console.WriteLine(formatted2);
Console.ReadLine();
```